# Tried a line integral and then did it using Stokes theorem, but I'm getting different results...

Tags: line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I'm getting two different results by using two methods that should be equivalent...

**"Find the line integral $\int x.dx+y.dy+(x^2+y^2).dz$ along the curve C. C is the intersection between paraboloid $z=2-x^2-y^2$ and cone $z=\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$. Verify using Stokes theorem."**

So I have the vector field $\overrightarrow F (x,y,z) = <x;y;x^2+y^2>$ and from an equation I got the intersection between the two surfaces:
$$
\begin{align}
z &= 2-x^2-y^2\\
x^2+y^2 &= 2-z\\
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} &= \sqrt{2-z}\\
z &= \sqrt{2-z}\\
z^2 &= 2-z\\
z^2+z-1 &= 0
\end{align}
$$
So either $z=1$ or $z=-2$, but  $z=-2$ is not in the positive half of the cone, so I discard it. From there I get that:
$$
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2 &= 2-1\\
x^2+y^2 &= 1
\end{align}
$$

If I parameterize the surfaces using cylindrical coordinates:
$$
x^2+y^2=r^2\\
x= r. cos(\theta)\\
y= r. sin(\theta)\\
z= 2-r^2
$$
with $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 2 \pi$ and $0\leqslant r \leqslant 1$.

Then my parameterization is $\alpha(\theta, r)= <r.cos (\theta); r. sin (\theta); 2-r^2>$

To get the normal vector I have to find $\alpha_r \times \alpha_\theta$:

$$\alpha_r = <cos(\theta); sin(\theta); -2r)>\\
\alpha_\theta = <-r.sin(\theta); r.cos(\theta); 0>$$
and this is done by:
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) & -2r \\
    -r.sin(\theta) & r.cos(\theta) & 0 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$
So from this operation, my normal vector is $\overrightarrow N = <2.r^2 . cos(\theta); 2.r^2.sin(\theta); r>$

Then, I proceed to obtain the line integral by the "regular" method and by Stokes theorem. First, by the regular method I got:

$$\int_C \overrightarrow F . \overrightarrow{ds} = \iint_S \overrightarrow F(\alpha(\theta, r)) \cdot (\alpha_r \times \alpha_\theta) \, dA$$
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 <r.cos(\theta); r.sin(\theta)>; r^2> \cdot <2.r^2.cos(\theta); 2.r^2.sin(\theta); r> dr \, d\theta =\\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (2.r^3.cos^2(\theta)+2.r^3.sin^2(\theta)+r^3) dr \, d\theta =\\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 2.r^3(cos(\theta)+sin(\theta)+r^3)dr \, d\theta = \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (2.r^3+r^3)dr \, d\theta= \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 3.r^3 dr \, d\theta = \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} ( \frac 34 r^4) |_0^1 . d\theta =\\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac 34 d\theta =\\
= ( \frac 34 \theta ) |_0^{2\pi}= \frac 32 \pi
$$

Then, by Stokes theorem I have to find the curl of $\overrightarrow F$ to calculate $\iint_S curl \overrightarrow F . \overrightarrow{ds}$

$$
curl \overrightarrow F = 2y-2x
$$

And by plugging the parameterization into this curl I get: $curl \overrightarrow F (r,\theta)=<2.r.sin(\theta); -2.r.cos(\theta); 0>$

Now I did $\int_C \overrightarrow F \cdot \overrightarrow {ds} = \iint_S curl \overrightarrow F \cdot \overrightarrow N \cdot ds$ and this is what I got:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 <2.r^2.cos(\theta); 2.r^2.sin(\theta)> \cdot <2.r.sin(\theta); -2.r.cos(\theta);0> dr \, d\theta= \\
=\int_0^{2\pi} \int0_1 (4.r^3.cos(\theta).sin(\theta)-4.r^3.cos(\theta).sin(\theta)+0) dr \, d\theta=\\
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 0 \, dr \, d\theta = 0
$$

So I got two different results and I'm not sure why...

Comment: You are asked to compute a line-integral, the regular one should only integrate over $\theta$, not over $r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing the procedures of Stokes' theorem when evaluating line integrals. First, we have

$$\underline{F}(x,y)=\left<x,y,x^2+y^2\right>$$

Now let $\underline{\gamma}(\theta)$ trace $C$, a circle of radius $1$ sitting at $z=1$, so

$$\underline{\gamma}(\theta)=\left<\cos\theta,\sin\theta,1\right>$$

The line integral is then

$$\oint_C\underline{F}(x,y)\cdot d\underline{\gamma}=\int_0^{2\pi}\underline{F}(\theta)\cdot\underline{\gamma}'(\theta)d\theta$$

Substituting and writing on the dot product gives

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(-\sin\theta\cos\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)d\theta=0$$

---

I think you got it, but remember curl of a vector field is another vector field, not a scalar field

$$\nabla\times\underline{F}(x,y)=2y\underline{i}-2x\underline{j}+0\underline{k}$$

Also, the dot product requires that both vectors are of the same dimension. $\left<a,b\right>\cdot\left<c,d,e\right>$ makes no sense

Comment: Thanks. I got it that I had written curl as a scalar field while it's not. But still, I'm not sure why your parameterization of a circle has only $\theta$ and doesn't have a r.

Comment: Because the radius of the circle is constant, so the vector that traces it goes up in the $z$ direction by $1$ to get to the plane, and then the $x$ and $y$ components trace the circle as if it were in the $x-y$ plane.

You're just tracing the curve, not the region bound by the curve, when evaluating line integrals.

Comment: So the parameterization done while using Stokes is not the same as the one done while using the "regular" line integral method?

Comment: Also another question: for Stokes, when I parameterize the surface do I get $z=1$ or $z=2-r^2$?

Comment: Yes, for line integrals, you parameterize the curve itself and for Stokes, you parameterize the actual surface. Both give the same result I believe in this case, but that is not true in general. You would parameterize the actual surface using a vector $\underline{r}(x,y)=x\underline{i}+y\underline{j}+(2-x^2-y^2)\underline{k}$ which you could transform to polar coordinates if you'd like